# recuperar uso da cpu com php

Tags: php

Bom montei o seguinte código em php, para me retornar o usa da CPU.

```
// Executa comando para consulta da CPU
exec('top -d 0 -n 5 -b | grep Cpu', $cpu);

// Monta array com os cores do processador
for($i=1; $i < count($cpu);$i++){
    $cores[] = $cpu[$i];
}

// Monta o array de resposta
$array = array(
"cpu" => array(
    "geral" => $cpu[0],
    "cores" => $cores
)
);

echo var_dump($array);
```

A resposta que eu tenho é:

```
"%Cpu(s):  8.5 us,  1.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 89.6 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.5 si,  0.0 st"
```

Bom queria ver apenas a % us, como faço para que o código me retorne só isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o `preg_match` para pegar somente `8.5` de `8.5 us`:

```
preg_match('/\d+\../', $array['cpu']['geral'], $cpu_us);

echo $cpu_us[0]; // deve imprimir: "8.5"
```

O código irá retornar a primeira sequência que atenda a expressão regular `\d+\..`, onde:

```
\d+ : 1 ou mais números
\.  : seguido por um ponto
.   : mais outro caractere qualquer
```

Resultando em `8.5` na variável `$cpu_us[0]`.